# Keeping track of location when doing Regex substitutions

Tags: c#, regex

Consider the following string `"a b c d efg hi j"`. If I am tracking position 7, the `"d"`, how do I keep track of it after I remove all spaces - e.g., for `"abcdefghij"` the updated position should be 4.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you first searched for the "d" and found at position 7, then search for it again after string substitution/removal to find it at position 4.

Comment: @elgonzo, then what happens if the string is "a b c dd efg hi j" or "a b cd d edfg hi j" or something?

Comment: @tenub, Then, how do you find the "d" in the first place? You have two. It is not an answer i can give you, it depends on **which "d" you are looking for**...

Comment: @elgonzo, he said he's tracking whatever character in the string is at position 7 initially, so by your solution it may not work necessarily in finding the correct one if there are others of the same character nearby.

Comment: @Tenub, ah, i got you now. Your argument certainly is valid. I guess the OP should really clarify his question then, because, well, it doesn't seem to make much sense to choose and track a character position (say 7) irrespective of whatever character would be at (or before/after) that position. I mean, there must be a reason/criteria why a certain position is chosen.

Comment: Ah, bugger it. I wrote an answer now, not requiring to know why the OP wants to track a particular position. :-D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to track a certain character position(s) in a string and it is not possible for you to find the character again using a simple character search after the string replacements happened, then you can recalculate the tracked position for each single string replacement.

Three cases need to be considered for the recalculation of the tracked string position:

1. The text to be replaced is located **before the tracked position**, and the tracked character is not part of the text to replace: Recalculate the tracked position like

   trackedPos += newSubstituteStringPortion.Length - ReplacedStringPortion.Length
2. The text to replace is located **behind the tracked position**: No need to recalculate, because the tracked position doesn't change.
3. The tracked position is **inside the text portion to be replaced**: In this case you need to agree upon a convention about what your code should do in this situation. Possible conventions could be:

   - The tracked position remains unchanged.
   - The tracked position is not valid anymore.
   - Try to find the tracked character in the substitute string. You will still need to define a convention about what your code should do if the character appears multiple times in the substitute string, though.

If [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) is the method of choice, then one of its overloads accepting a [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) delegate can be used to recalculate the tracked position.

Such a MatchEvaluator delegate could look like this:

```
public string TrackPositionMatchEvaluator(Match match)
{
    if (match.Index + match.Length <= trackedPosition)
    {
        // Case #1 (see explanation above)
        trackedPos += substituteString.Length - match.Length;
    }
    else if (match.Index <= trackedPosition)
    {
        // Case #3 (see explanation above)
        ... here put the implementation for your convention(s) of case #3
    }

    // Case #2 (see explanation above) doesn't do any recalculation...

    return substituteString;
}
```

If your current code uses some other "ReplaceAll" function not using such a delegate, you might need to change this into a loop doing single replacements in a sequential manner, so that you can apply the rules given above. Depending on how you obtain the offsets of the string portions to be replaced, this loop should probably do the replacements "backwards", i.e. from the back of the string to its front.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the log of changes and corresponding positions made by a Regex substitution?

Comment: @tofutim, i believe you could. There are overloads of Regex.Replace which accept a `MatchEvaluator`. The MatchEvaluator you would need to implement yourself, and inside your MatchEvaluator you would also implement the code for recording replacement positions, lengths, and other information you might need -- or perhaps just do the recalculation of the tracked position there...

Comment: @tofutim, i updated my answer with a simple example implementation of a MatchEvaluator delegate for doing the recalculation of the tracked position. (Note, that you will still have to decide about what should happen for case #3.)